# WinJS ListView - displaying items horizontal

Tags: javascript, listview, winjs

How can you stop ListView from adding items vertically and make them display in a horizontal grid instead.

for example

1,2,3,4

5,6,7,8

**instead of**

1,3,5,7

2,4,6,8

Googling suggests the below but it doesn't make any difference.

```
this.listView.winControl.layout = new WinJS.UI.GridLayout();
this.listView.winControl.layout.orientation = "horizontal";
```

Comment: It should work, where did you put this codes? Could you give more codes?

Comment: oddly setting the orientation to "vertical" did the job! :)